# PHP Login - Password input - Special characters? - Centos 5 System

Tags: php, apache, security, centos

I have a CentOS 5 VPS and I have just installed my website there. But I have problems that when I'm inserting special characters into the password field like: ' (apostophe) or something like that, I always get the error, that this password is incorrect :/ I guess this is because of the Linux System. Am I right? Or maybe because of te sanitizing I'm doing?

I'd be gald if anyone could help me.

EDIT:

```
function array_sanitize(&$item) {
    $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($item)));
}
```

Comment: check whether magic quote is enabled or not!

Comment: yes its enabled, could it be the problem?

Comment: yes,it's the problem! I'll post how to disable it!

Comment: I have disabled it, but its still doing that :/ Maybe because I have an array sanitize for all the registration fields. I don't know how to get the password out of it and save it alone.

Comment: Did you restarted apache? 2- It can be, can you post your code here? sanitation  part!

Comment: Yep I have restarted, but still the same. Here is the simple sanitization (Updated my first post)

Comment: `htmlentities` should be used for preventing XSS not escaping data! remove it and test again! Also I don't understand why did you use `strip_tags`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18715/discussion-between-death-and-user1406071)

Comment: This is for sanitizing all my HTML form. That is why it needs htmlentities to escape XSS, when the user enters his data. OR I'm wrong?

Comment: `htmlentities` is an *output stage* function, used only for when you drop text into an HTML document. `mysql_real_escape_string` is used only when you're creating an SQL query with submitted values (don't do that - use parameterised queries). Neither of these - nor `strip_tags` -  are at all suitable for an input filter stage; they will be mangling your input in varied unhelpful ways. Any inconsistency in this mangling will result in non-matching data like your password. You cannot correctly handle string escaping issues at the input stage - this is a common PHP mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your magic quote is enabled, then you should turn it off:
Edit these in your php.ini:

```
; Magic quotes
;

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Or you can put this in `.htaccess` in document root:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

If you want to know about magic quote:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: I have turned off, but its still bad :/

Answer (score 0):

hmm this sounds like a input escaping issue to me, or some setting in the website.
try to trace the path of the inputs to the actual query that executes and checks for a valid username/password. This is all i can write without actual code.

P.S i can only post answers that is why i am posting it like this.